# Do spaces in \cite make a difference?

Tags: spacing, bibtex, citing

I just found the hard way that it matters.

For example,

```
\cite{aref, bref}
```

is different from

```
\cite{aref,bref}
```

Notice the space after the comma in first one. If it does matter, this looks real silly to me.

I just need to verify if this is the case.

Just to add, I am using **Miktex** and **Texmaker**

This is how it's looking now:

```
\cite{jiang2006research,datta2006distributed,bandyopadhyay2006clustering}
```

Before it was:

```
\cite{jiang2006research, datta2006distributed, bandyopadhyay2006clustering}
```

Here is a full example of code which fails:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{jair, theapa, rawfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Abstracts will go here.

\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{Introduction}

\subsection{Thesis Background}

As expected, most of the work involved combination of the disciplines of \textit{Data Mining} and \textit{Computer Networks} \cite{jiang2006research, datta2006distributed, bandyopadhyay2006clustering}.

\vskip 0.2in
\bibliographystyle{theapa}
\bibliography{refs}


\end{document}
```

refs.bib looks as follows:

```
@article{bandyopadhyay2006clustering,
  title={Clustering distributed data streams in peer-to-peer environments},
  author={Bandyopadhyay, S. and Giannella, C. and Maulik, U. and Kargupta, H. and Liu, K. and Datta, S.},
  journal={Information Sciences},
  volume={176},
  number={14},
  pages={1952--1985},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}


@article{datta2006distributed,
  title={Distributed data mining in peer-to-peer networks},
  author={Datta, S. and Bhaduri, K. and Giannella, C. and Wolff, R. and Kargupta, H.},
  journal={Internet Computing, IEEE},
  volume={10},
  number={4},
  pages={18--26},
  year={2006},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{jiang2006research,
  title={Research issues in data stream association rule mining},
  author={Jiang, N. and Gruenwald, L.},
  journal={ACM Sigmod Record},
  volume={35},
  number={1},
  pages={14--19},
  year={2006},
  publisher={ACM}
}


@book{datta2008probabilistic,
  title={Probabilistic approximate algorithms for distributed data mining in peer-to-peer networks},
  author={Datta, S.},
  year={2008},
  publisher={ProQuest}
}
```

Comment: Can you please give the code that you found *the hard way* ?

Comment: @HarishKumar: Code added, btw, I am using package jair, theapa and rawfonts and nothing else, except any that gets included by default.

Comment: Oh!. This won't help. Can you please give a code from `\doumentclass...\end{document}` like I gave in the answer? Also include those packages which are suspects!. If they are not standard packages (i.e., not found on CTAN), you may give their link also.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Ok, added the full code that is failing :). Hope you can crack better at it ;)

Comment: Dear @Shamim Hafiz, where can we find `jair` and `theapa`? They don't look standard.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz You are using a very old package `theapa.sty` that redefines `\cite` in a wrong way. There are more recent packages that provide APA citation style.

Comment: @HarishKumar: I am working on a "Data Mining" project and we are supposed to use the JAIR format. On Googling for JAIR, I found references to this file. The actual files were obtained from an example work.

Comment: @egreg Would you please recommend some packages suitable for working in JAIR format. Thanks.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz I don't know about JAIR; but the file they provide is from 1993 and is written in ugly LaTeX. However it's not responsible for the failure of `\cite` with spaces in its argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trust your own eyes `;-)`

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@ARTICLE{mwe2012,
  author = {Smith, A. and Johnson, B. and Willians, C.},
  title = {The three most common surnames in the United States of America},
  journal = {Review of Useless Knowledge},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {8},
  number = {1},
  pages = {290--290}
}

@ARTICLE{mwe2011,
  author = {Miller, J. and Brown, D.},
  title = {Most used surnames in fake passports},
  journal = {Journal of Nosense Ranks},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {5},
  number = {3},
  pages = {1--130},
  pmid = {1234567},
  url = {http://www.mwe.com/mwe2011},
  doi = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/jnr.2011.01.01},
}
\end{filecontents*}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


\section{First section}
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt~\cite{mwe2011,mwe2012}.

\noindent nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt~\cite{mwe2011,   mwe2012}.


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

From the comments above, it seems you want to use APA style citations. The following code illustrates the solution (where I used `apacite` package)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{apacite} %% for APA style
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bandyopadhyay2006clustering,
  title={Clustering distributed data streams in peer-to-peer environments},
  author={Bandyopadhyay, S. and Giannella, C. and Maulik, U. and Kargupta, H. and Liu, K. and Datta, S.},
  journal={Information Sciences},
  volume={176},
  number={14},
  pages={1952--1985},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}


@article{datta2006distributed,
  title={Distributed data mining in peer-to-peer networks},
  author={Datta, S. and Bhaduri, K. and Giannella, C. and Wolff, R. and Kargupta, H.},
  journal={Internet Computing, IEEE},
  volume={10},
  number={4},
  pages={18--26},
  year={2006},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{jiang2006research,
  title={Research issues in data stream association rule mining},
  author={Jiang, N. and Gruenwald, L.},
  journal={ACM Sigmod Record},
  volume={35},
  number={1},
  pages={14--19},
  year={2006},
  publisher={ACM}
}


@book{datta2008probabilistic,
  title={Probabilistic approximate algorithms for distributed data mining in peer-to-peer networks},
  author={Datta, S.},
  year={2008},
  publisher={ProQuest}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


\section{First section}
tempor invidunt~\cite{jiang2006research,datta2008probabilistic}.

\noindent 
tempor invidunt~\cite{jiang2006research,   datta2006distributed}.


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And your code (with `apacite`) will be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite} %% for APA style
\usepackage{jair,rawfonts}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bandyopadhyay2006clustering,
  title={Clustering distributed data streams in peer-to-peer environments},
  author={Bandyopadhyay, S. and Giannella, C. and Maulik, U. and Kargupta, H. and Liu, K. and Datta, S.},
  journal={Information Sciences},
  volume={176},
  number={14},
  pages={1952--1985},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}


@article{datta2006distributed,
  title={Distributed data mining in peer-to-peer networks},
  author={Datta, S. and Bhaduri, K. and Giannella, C. and Wolff, R. and Kargupta, H.},
  journal={Internet Computing, IEEE},
  volume={10},
  number={4},
  pages={18--26},
  year={2006},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{jiang2006research,
  title={Research issues in data stream association rule mining},
  author={Jiang, N. and Gruenwald, L.},
  journal={ACM Sigmod Record},
  volume={35},
  number={1},
  pages={14--19},
  year={2006},
  publisher={ACM}
}


@book{datta2008probabilistic,
  title={Probabilistic approximate algorithms for distributed data mining in peer-to-peer networks},
  author={Datta, S.},
  year={2008},
  publisher={ProQuest}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Abstracts will go here.

\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\label{Introduction}

\subsection{Thesis Background}

As expected, most of the work involved combination of the disciplines of \textit{Data Mining} and \textit{Computer Networks} \cite{jiang2006research,         datta2006distributed,                                          bandyopadhyay2006clustering}.

\vskip 0.2in

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Compile and see for yourself. *Don't* use `theapa.bst` and `theapa.sty` They are old. Instead use `apacite`.

Comment: Hey, I want to read these journals regularly !!!11 ;-D

Comment: @Speravir: `:-)`. I picked up[ those in this site only. Liked them very much and using them `;-)`

Comment: Thanks for the code update. Here is the link that you requested:
"www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/information/.../jair.sty "
You would need to actually google it and it's not a raw link which would open up straightway.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz: See the update. Don't use `theapa`.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Thanks for the update and advice. egreg mentioned that, jair.sty is too old. Do you have any suggestion for it's alternative. As for a bit of humor, if I try to Google jair style, I get an alternate suggestion for hairstyle :P. The concerning part is, the phrase jair style might be outdated.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz: I think it is better if you contact the editor of `Journal of Artificial Intelligence Research` for a new `.sty` file.

Comment: @HarishKumar: I searched in jair.org and looks like this is all they have. Anyway, I am good to go for now. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz: Thanks. Upvoting the answers and accepting (by checking the green check mark below vote count) the answer that is very useful to you are the ways of  expressing thanks here in TeX.Sx.